# Unable to join pandas dataframe on string type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames objects whose columns are as below

Dataframe 1:

```
df.dtypes
```

**Output:**

```
ImageID       object
Source        object
LabelName     object
Confidence     int64
dtype: object
```

Dataframe 2:

```
a.dtypes
```

**Output:**

```
LabelName       object
ReadableName    object
dtype: object
```

Here, i am trying to combine these two dataframes as below

```
combined =  df.join(a,on='LabelName')
```

But, i am getting the following error

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

But, i am merging them on LabelName, which has only strings (object datatype)

Am i missing something here?

Comment: try`df.merge(a, on='LabelName', how='outer')`

Comment: I think the easiest step forward is to share a small amount of data from each dataframe. Using for instance df1.head().

Comment: You can use `pd.concat` as you have str and int in your dataframe

Answer (score 24, accepted):

About the [`on` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), the documentation says:

> Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, otherwise joins index-on-index.

Note that `join()` always uses `other.index`.  You can try this:

```
df.join(a.set_index('LabelName'), on='LabelName')
```

Or use `df.merge()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is problem some columns are integers along with string in DataFrame1 while all are strings in DataFrame2 which is causing the problem.

Simplest solution is cast all columns to strings:

```
pd.merge(df1.astype(str),df2.astype(str), how='outer')
```

As the Value Error suggesting itself use concat:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Confidence column to an object first because there is a dtype mismatch.

```
 df['Confidence'].apply(str)
```