# Python 3.7 Unable to merge 2 dataframe's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, valueerror

I am trying to merge two dataframe's together. df1 is based on a merge of other files (GTFS -routes,trips,stop_times) and df2 is the stop_times file

When I try the merge, I get a ValueError msg:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I want to merge the df's, and I have confirmed that the two keys I try to merge on are both string objects.

I use the following to try to merge the two df's

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='inner', on='stop_id')
```

I have tried writing and reading the df to file and back again, as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649853/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-get-valueerror), as well as casting both columns to the string object using `df.stop_id = df.stop_id.astype('str')`

I read in the files explicitly indicating all columns are strings

```
df2= pd.read_csv('stops.txt', dtype={'stop_id': 'str',
                                     'stop_code': 'str',
                                     'stop_name': 'str',
                                     'stop_lat': 'str',
                                     'stop_lon': 'str',
                                     'location_type': 'str',
                                     'parent_station': 'str',
                                     'wheelchair_boarding': 'str',
                                     'platform_code': 'str'})
```

and check the data types

```
df1.stop_id.dtype
df2.stop_id.dtype
```

both produce

```
dtype('O')
```

But the merge still fails with the above error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please look and the correct answer for this question. I hope this will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902909/unable-to-join-pandas-dataframe-on-string-type

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframes with the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge both dataframe

First convert `stop_id` in `str` in both dataframes

```
df1['stop_id'] = df1['stop_id'].astpye(str)
df2['stop_id'] = df2['stop_id'].astpye(str)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['stop_id'])
```