# ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns error when joining by cooridnates

Tags: python, pandas

I have following two dataframes by common field `comm`

DataFrame I (vv)

```
V_Id      object
V_Time    object
comm      object
dtype: object

V_Id    V_Time  comm
0   1234    2020-02-02-10-15-20 (166.0467, 35.2363)
1   1234    2020-02-02-10-15-22 (166.047, 35.2363)
2   1234    2020-02-02-10-15-23 (166.0473, 35.2363)
3   1234    2020-02-02-10-15-25 (166.0475, 35.2363)
```

DataFrame II (rr)

```
R_Id    object
comm    object
dtype: object


R_Id    comm
0   One (166.0467, 35.2371)
1   One (166.0468, 35.2371)
2   One (166.0468, 35.2371)
```

I get following error, when I run `vv.join(rr, on=['comm'])`

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

How would I join/merge by `comm`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to merge 2 dataframes but get ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649853/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-get-valueerror)

Answer (score 0):

It is a slight variation of this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902909/unable-to-join-pandas-dataframe-on-string-type)

```
vv.join(rr.set_index('comm'), on='comm', how='outer')
```

I have changed the first comm value of rr to (166.0467, 35.2363). So the two dataframes have at least one element in common. Output:

```
        V_Id    V_Time                  comm                    R_Id
0.0     1234.0  2020-02-02-10-15-20     (166.0467, 35.2363)     One
1.0     1234.0  2020-02-02-10-15-22     (166.047, 35.2363)      NaN
2.0     1234.0  2020-02-02-10-15-23     (166.0473, 35.2363)     NaN
3.0     1234.0  2020-02-02-10-15-25     (166.0475, 35.2363)     NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN                     (166.0468, 35.2371)     One
NaN     NaN     NaN                     (166.0468, 35.2371)     One
```